# drop event doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a calendar. I have multiple droppables besides each other (upside down). On top of those droppables I have two draggable elements which are also resizable. Each droppable is 25px in height and 200px in width. The first draggable is 60px in height (element 1) and the other (element 2) is 20px in height. My problem is when I drag element 2 over element 1 and drop it between two droppables, the drop event doesn't fire. In all other drag and drop situations it works perfectly, the drop event fires.

HTML (snippet off because there are a lot of these droppables):

```
<div style="height:25px; width:200px; border-bottom:1px solid black;" class="droppable">
      <div class="time">Kl 8:00 </div>
</div>   
<div style="height:25px; width:200px; border-bottom:1px solid black;" class="droppable">
      <div class="time">Kl 8:15 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery (Here I'm creating my appointments (draggables)):

```
  appointment1 = $("<div style='height: 60px; width: 150px;  position: absolute; left: 508px; top: 214px;' id='drag2' class='draggable'><div><span class='gage1'>Drag</span></div></div>");
     appointment1.appendTo("#gage1");
     appointment2 = $(" <div class='draggable' id='drag1' style='height:20px; width:150px; position: absolute; left: 508x; top: 270px;'><div><span class='gage2'>Drag</span></div></div>");
     appointment2.appendTo("#gage2");
```

And here I have my drop event:

```
    $(".droppable").droppable({

        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("drop");

        }
    });
```

Comment: What language is this in? Can you post an example of your code?

Comment: 1. Do you have elements that are `draggable()` 2. Does the container of the draggables have a `position:relative`. 3. Does the same element have a `.sortable()` bind to it?, I had problems in past.

Answer (score 1):

try to see if other methods do fire, like the over() method.

Comment: the elements are binded. After I append them I call a function which binds them.

Comment: The overevent works, Ive found another solution, Ive changed the heights on my draggables, and Ive used the grid option on the draggable. This means that its not possible to have half on half draggable item on 2 droppables. If its not clear my solution Ive be happy to give a more detail description and post some code.